# How can I get the json file from ResponseEntity?

Tags: json, spring-boot

I have my web service consuming another web service. in my web service I modify some fields of the json. then in postman it is consumed ok.
Now I need to convert the ResponseEntity to a .json file to save it to a folder on my computer, but the attempt has failed.

Any ideas?

my controller current:

```
@Controller
public class SiviccController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SiviccController.class);
    private String url = "http://localhost:9090/url_1";

    @GetMapping("/url_2")
    @ResponseBody
    public Body sivicc() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(Factory.timeoutHttp());
        try {
            return restTemplate.getForObject(url, Body.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Body body = new Body();
            body.setIserror(true);
            log.info(e.getMessage());
            return body;
        }
    }
}
```

Matheus Cirillo works perfectly with the following code:

```
@Controller
public class SiviccController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SiviccController.class);
    private String url = "http://localhost:9090/url_1";

    @GetMapping("/url_2")
    @ResponseBody
    public Body sivicc() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(Factory.timeoutHttp());
        try {
            String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("my-file.json", true));
            writer.append(response);
            writer.close();
            return restTemplate.getForObject(url, Body.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Body body = new Body();
            body.setIserror(true);
            log.info(e.getMessage());
            return body;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the web service that you were consuming before now generates a token. That's why I change getForObject to exchange and I consume it well, but I apply the same logic to save the json in a folder on my computer, but it generates a failure in two lines:

```
@Controller
public class SiviccController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SiviccController.class);
    private String url = "http://localhost:9090/url_1";

    @GetMapping("/url_2")
    @ResponseBody
    public Body sivicc() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.set("Authorization", "bearer 8P7oM_ZDhB3TYolVkB1MLtM734DrrUSMVEFuiy3u");
        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);               
        headers.add("User-Agent", "Spring's RestTemplate" );
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                request,
                //Body.class,
                String.class,
                1
        );
  
        try {   
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("my-file.json", true));
            writer.append(response);//Error: The method append(CharSequence) in the type Writer is not applicable for the arguments (ResponseEntity<String>)
            writer.close();
            return response.getBody();//Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Body
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Body body = new Body();
            body.setIserror(true);
            log.info(e.getMessage());
            return body;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe also post the error you're getting as well?

Comment: answer updated @Dante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Response type from `getForObject` to `String.class`, then, use the `BufferedWriter` to write the file.

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
String response = rest.getForObject("http://example.com/", String.class);

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("my-file.json", true));
writer.append(response);
writer.close();
```

---

**Edit**

The [RestTemplate#exchange](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-) returns a `ResponseEntity<T>`, not a `String`.

In your case, it will return a `ResponseEntity<String>`.

That's why you're unable to write the object. To do so, you need to get the body from the `ResponseEntity` object. Use the method [ResponseEntity#getBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html#getBody--)

Something like this:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class, 1);

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("my-file.json", true));
// here you are getting the String with the response.getBody() method,
// so buffered writer can write the file
writer.append(response.getBody());
writer.close();
```

Comment: Matheus Cirillo, I was able to save the json on my computer, however I get the json without the modifications that I make. brings me the original json. I appreciate your help.

Comment: ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET,request,String.class,1);  
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("my-file.json", true));
writer.append(response.getBody());//I get json without modifications
writer.close();
     
return restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET,request,Body.class,1).getBody();//in Postman ok

Comment: What modifications you mean?

Comment: I have my web service consuming a json from another web service. in my web service I modify some fields of the json.

Comment: then, just write the json after you modify the json

Comment: I think the body.class brings the modified values ​​and I am replacing it with String.class. There is where the problem is and I don't know how to do what you tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

add to pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

1. Use the Jackson API ObjectMapper class to convert Java Object to a JSON string
2. Use the BufferedWriter to write the file. @Matheus Cirillo

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
          json = mapper.writeValueAsString(response.getBody());
          System.out.println("ResultingJSONstring = " + json);
          BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("my-file.json", true));
        writer.append(json);
        writer.close();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

thanks for your help =)